# Failed to re-package resources. building error from Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk

I'm trying to build my first android project from Unity..

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
>
> ..\tools_r25.2.3-windows\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe package
>   --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "../tools_r25.2.3-windows\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_
>
> stderr[ AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that
>   matches the given name (at 'theme' with value
>   '@style/UnityThemeSelector').
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/app_icon').
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name (at 'banner' with value '@drawable/app_banner').
>
> AndroidManifest.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches
>   the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
>
> ] stdout[ Configurations:  (default)
>
> Files:   AndroidManifest.xml
>       Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

I'm aware of the fact that I'm not the first to have a similar error, yet I've not bean able to fix this yet and would appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Do you use any plugins?

Comment: no. Should I be using any?

Comment: What is your Package Name?

Comment: Since you know this question has been asked multiple times, can you describe what is the difference between your problem and others'? What have you tried so far?

Comment: com.meirsho.test2

Comment: I've tried downloading different versions of SDK, changing settings inside Unity and changing locations of different files in the SDK Files..to no success yet.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any custom plugins or `AndroidManifest.xml` files. Because this error mostly occurs when there are custom plugins.

Comment: You have missing files: *`Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/UnityThemeSelector')`* I don't know how or why, but that's what your underlying error is.